# Android listview with both onTouch and onItemLongClick listener

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, ontouchlistener, onitemlongclicklistener

Hello I'm still developing an Android application. Earlier I created a listview with OnTouch listener to swipe and double tap and OnItemLongClick to perform drag and drop. This was with a simple, just containing a textview
Now I changed to a custom listview row with a textview and a button. With this configuration just one of both gesture detections are usable. When I put android:longclickable to true, the drag and drop is possible, but it doesn't detect OnTouch. This works also the other way around. Does anyone have a solution to use both gesture detections?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView   
     android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp"  
     android:textSize="16sp" >  
    </TextView>

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/rowImgButton"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:background="#ffff00"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rowTextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use a GestureDetector in the onTouchListener to detect the longPresses

Comment: @I-I I tried to use the onLongPress, but this gesture should start a drag and drop action. That's not possible with the onLongPress.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to do. It might help if you post some code of what you are working on.

Comment: I posted an answer, I think it should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: The purpose of both gestures is explained in my question. I don't understand what's not clear for you?

Comment: The combination of using both gestures isn't the problem, but the action that it should perform is specific. Drag and drop after LongClick.

Comment: I think the problem was that `public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)` does not include the position to get the clicked item, which in `public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` it is.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for, you can create a GestureDetector:

```
myGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                //Handle long press
            }
        });
myGestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);
```

And then in your onTouch method:

```
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
    myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    ...
}
```

Then when the user performs a long press, the onLongPress method should fire